# use ichoropleth function in rMaps to plot other countries

Tags: javascript, json, r, choropleth

I just found an interesting package called rMaps in R and I found there is a function called `ichoropleth()` which can plot the map of a country (or a region?). I think there is currently no help file in R to check all the arguments in this function however I find the code of this function in this link [https://github.com/ramnathv/rMaps/blob/master/R/Datamaps.R#L43]. I saw the default setting for map argument is 'usa' and I am thinking what if I want to plot other countries and what the code would be like? Say for example is nz for New Zealand, au for Australia? uk for United Kingdom? or something else?

I am really keen to know the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom layer for your map, but first you will need to convert your data to TopoJSON. I followed these instructions http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/ to convert my shapefile to TopoJSON. In your ichoropleth function you can specify your map as follows:

```
d1$set(geographyConfig = list(dataUrl = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/file_name.json")
```

For more info on this topic check this post:https://github.com/ramnathv/rMaps/issues/6. or take a look to this repo for a working example https://github.com/Arevaju/shiny-maps.

Cheers!